# How to specify ip address of a local machine and a port number in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, url

I have the following code.Instead of value of url: 'http://isaacs.couchone.com/registry/_all_docs', i need to specify an ip address of a local machine ,say 10.30.52.75 and a port number 3000,where my application is running.How to specify ip address and port number using node.js as a value of url, with out affecting the working of the remaining source code.

```
var request = require('request');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var es = require('event-stream');
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.createClient();

request({url: 'http://isaacs.couchone.com/registry/_all_docs'})
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    client.publish('NewTopic',JSON.stringify(data));
    client.on('connect', function() {
      client.end();
    });
    console.error(data);
    return data
  }))
```

Comment: If you app is bound to the loopback device as well (or to all IPs for that matter, 0.0.0.0), you could try `http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the host IP is 10.30.52.75 and the host port is 3000, your code snippet becomes:

```
var request = require('request');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var es = require('event-stream');
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.createClient();
var url = 'http://10.30.52.75:3000';

request({url: url})
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    client.publish('NewTopic',JSON.stringify(data));
    client.on('connect', function() {
      client.end();
    });
    console.error(data);
    return data
  }))
```